# HTML5 Video element not playing an .mp4 with no audio codec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

I'm trying to upload a video to a Angular app using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). All works fine until I try and upload a .mp4 video with no audio codec. The video element shows, it shows the correct duration in the control panel, it just doesn't play. Clicking play does nothing, the first frame is not shown.

If I upload any other .mp4 that contains audio the video plays without error.

Below is the information I can see about the file that is failing, as you can see only the video codec is listed for this file.

[image]

Here is the 'more info' for another .mp4 file that has audio, this one uploads perfectly fine and plays in the HTML5 video element with no errors.

[image]

As you can see, the video that works states the audio codec as AAC, which is expected for .mp4, and shows Audio Channels "2", i'm unsure of the purpose of 'Audio Channels' is in all honesty.

I've been debugging this thing all day and the only difference in files that I can see is in the above images.

Should HTML5 video player play a .mp4 video without any audio codec listed?

What leads me to think the audio has a role to play in this is w3schools description of an Mpeg-4 file:

> MP4 = MPEG 4 files with H264 video codec and AAC audio codec

Has anyone had this issue before?

**Edit**

After adding a listener to the error event on the video I can see that I get a MediaError object with code 3 as a value, so this is a decoding issue [I can see](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_error.asp).

Screenshot below

[image]

**Further edit**

I've now debugged this as far as going into Chromes 'media-internals' logs. The error Chrome is encountering is now confirmed to be because of the missing audio, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Unsure why an error isn't clearly thrown because of this. Is this the end of the line, it's weird because if I upload the video to Facebook it uploads just fine.

Comment: have you tried attaching an onerror event before playing the video?

Comment: No, didn't realize video supported that! I will add that in now and update the question with a fix or the error info. cheers.

Comment: @r3wt So that did turn up an error, it's a decoding error. Debugging this now, have you experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to check if the .mp4 file is properly converted. I've already checked it on my computer and it should be normally played - just video with no audio (Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome 51.0.2704.106).

Use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) to check the available media tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4
```

Then try to use the source with audio track and convert it to one without an audio. This command will remove all audio tracks:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -vcodec copy -an output_file.mp4
```

HTML5 specification doesn't tell what should happen when we don't have a proper codec for one of the media tracks. Just for reference - [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element)

It's always a good idea to check the playback on any other player, VLC is a good one for reference.